# dojo toolkit closing external dialog

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying since yesterday how to close external dialog after click on button

this shows dialog:

```
<div id="external_dialog" 
    data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog" 
    title="Edytuj dane firmowe" 
    href="/external/dialog" 
    style="overflow:auto; width: 365px; height: 280px;">
</div>
```

and the dialog in external file is just a simple form

```
<form data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form">    
    <script type="dojo/event" data-dojo-event="onSubmit" data-dojo-args="e">
        dojo.stopEvent(e);
        if(!this.isValid()){ return; }
        $.post('ajax/something', 
                 {name: $('#FM-name').val()},
                 function() {
                     alert('ok')
                 });
    </script>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" style="width: 330px">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><strong>Company name: </strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" required="true" name="name" id="FM-name" placeholder="" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>    

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="FC-submit" dojoType="dojox.form.BusyButton" label="Submit" busyLabel="Please wait..." />
    <input type="button" value="Close" label="Close" id="FC-close" dojoType="dijit.form.Button"} />

</form>
```

BTW. submit works perfectly, but what should be related with close button?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference of the dialog first using `dijit.byId`, then use `hide` function to hide the dialog.

In the click event handler of the close button, try

```
dijit.byId('external_dialog').hide();
```

Comment: I tried this and didn't work for me. I suppose the that is due to external. Closing has to be used in a different way :(